# Rails search location and then filter by category

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have an app where the user can find a meal by its location, and then he could refine by categories. (meal and category are different models).

With what I have now, I can find a meal from its location, but when I refine it display all the other meals...

**How can I keep "in memory" the location and then filter by categories ?**

***meals_controller.rb***

```
class MealsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :find_meal, only: [:show, :update, :edit, :destroy]


  def index
    filter_by_location if params[:query].present?
    meal_filter = MealsFilter.new(params)
    @meals ||= meal_filter.filter
    @meals_count = @meals.count
    #add_markers_on_map
    @categories = Category.all
  end

  #[other actions come here]

  private

  def find_meal
    @meal = Meal.find(params[:id])
  end

  def meal_params
    params.require(:meal)
    .permit(:menu_name,
            :price,
            :portion,
            :availability,
            :category_id,
            :location,
            images: [],
            ingredients_attributes: [:id, :name, :_destroy])
  end


  def filter_by_location
    @meals = Meal.search(params[:query][:location]) if params[:query][:location].present?
  end

end
```

***app/services/meals_filter.rb***

```
class MealsFilter

  def initialize(params)
    @params = params
    @meals = Meal.where('availability  >= ?', Date.today )
  end

  def filter
    #filter_by_location
    filter_by_category
    @meals
  end

  private

  def filter_by_category
   if @params[:categories] != nil && @params[:categories].size != 0 && !@params[:categories].include?("all")
     @meals = @meals.joins(:category).where("categories.name IN (?)", @params[:categories])
   end
  end

  # def filter_by_location
  #   @meals = Meal.where('location LIKE?', @params[:query][:location]) if @params[:query][:location].present?
  # end
end
```

#### Edit

This is my categories filter:

```
<section class="choice" id="normal-choice">
        <form action="/meals" method="get" class= "normal-form">
          <ul class="list-unstyled">
            <% @categories.each do |category| %>
              <li>
                <label class="categories">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="categories[]" value="<%= category.name %>"
                    <%= "checked" if !params[:categories].nil? && params[:categories].include?(category.name) %>>
                  <span>

                    <%= category.name %>
                  </span>

                </label>
              </li>
            <% end %>
          </ul>
          <input class="valid-btn" type="submit" value="Filtrer">
        </form>
      </section>
```

Comment: You could use a temporary table and delete the record when You are done with it.

Comment: How should I do this please?

Comment: You can pass location to MealFilter initialize.

Comment: You've got a few options here: Using SessionStorage, creating DB entries etc. However in this case I personally would keep it simple with a hidden_field.

User searches for meal - results returned. 

In the hidden_field for your category filter you can hold all the original meal id's and they can then be submitted alongside the category search.

Comment: @Eoghain, thanks for your suggestion, I am a little bit confused how can I add the hidden field in here? ( edited)